# What's the use of observable array and mapping plugin in Knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

If my JSON data can be converted directly using ko.observableArray then what's the use of Mapping plugin because as far as I know mapping plugin is used for converting JSON into knockout object. I am new to KO don't know much about it

Comment: i guess you are confused `binding` with `mapping`. Please read this: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of an `observableArray` aren't automatically observable themselves; subscriptions (including bindings) to an `observableArray` respond to changes to the array itself (such as adding or removing elements) but not to changes to the content of an individual element. If you want the latter to happen, you need to turn the (relevant) properties of each object in the array into `observable`s, and that's what the mapping plugin does for you.

Consider:

```
var vm={};
vm.dummy=[{num:'one'}, {num:'two'}, {num:'three'}, {num:'four'}];
// Create observableArray of plain objects
vm.oa1=ko.observableArray(vm.dummy);
// Create observableArray of objects with observable properties
vm.oa2=ko.mapping.fromJS(vm.dummy);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Along with:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: oa1"><li data-bind="text: num"></li></ul>
<ul data-bind="foreach: oa2"><li data-bind="text: num"></li></ul>
```

Now in the console:

```
vm.oa1()[1].num = 'five'
```

Nothing changes in the display

```
vm.oa1()[1].num
```

five

```
vm.oa1()[1].num('five');
```

Error, because the element isn't an observable

```
vm.oa2()[1].num('five');
```

The second list changes

Comment: This is a useful answer. You probably want to update it, though, to make `vm` an `object` instead of being `undefined`. So instead of `var vm;`, use `var vm = {};` or `var vm = {} || vm;`    http://jsbin.com/adOjuNO/1/edit

Comment: Thanks; I must still be writing Perl in JavaScript (Perl "autovivifies" hash/object references).